# System broken after apt clear cache and rm /logs/*

Tags: 18.04

I had zero bytes left so I executed these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
rm /var/logs/*
```

After a reboot it's not responding, I can only login using Hetzner Rescue.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about desktop, server etc.  Can you login via terminal?

Comment: @guiverc it's server, I was thinking that mentioning Hetzner cloud will make it clear, yes I can login but the actual system is mounted on /mnt.